# Set tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to make some manipulations with tick labels in matplotlib. But it seems that code does not do what I want, and I have no idea why? There is no labels.

```
In[1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
       import numpy as np

In[2]: x = np.arange(0,10)

In[3]: plt.plot(x,x)

       locs, labs = plt.xticks()
       plt.xticks(locs[1:], labs[1:])

       plt.show()
```

[image]

Any help please! What I want is to delete first label on x axis:
[image]
I'm using:
python 3.5.2
matplotlib 1.5.3
win 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
locs, labs = plt.xticks() 
plt.xticks(locs[1:]) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Here you go]

Answer (score 6):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, x)
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(ticks[1:])
plt.show()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: I'm not familiar with this domain, so this answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct answer to your question, rather than a remedy to your predicament.

```
>>> locs, labs = plt.xticks()
>>> locs
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
>>> labs
<a list of 10 Text xticklabel objects>
```

Notice that when you make a *get* call to **xticks** it yields a one-dimensional array of locations for tick marks and a list of *objects*. However, when you make a *put* call to **xticks** it expects an array-like collection of locations and an array-like collection of *strings*. For some reason, **xticks** seems to have failed to croak upon being given that list of objects.